# Negativity of an analytic function on $[0,1)$

Tags: analysis, analytic-functions, tauberian-theory

I want to show the following function is negative for $z\in [0,1)$:
$$f(z) = -1 + z^2(z-1) + 2\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k z^{(2k+1)^2+1}. $$

By Tauberian theorem, I know that $\lim_{z\to 1^-}f(z)=0$. I also know that $\lim_{z\to 1^-} f'(z)=1$ so there is a close enough neighborhood of $1$ that $f$ is always negative. However, I want to give more details to show the negativity of the function $f$. I have included a plot of $f$ below. The function diverges at $x=1$, hence it is not easy to estimate it by truncating the series for $z\to 1$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Very close to $z=1$ we have
$$z^{(2k+1)^2+1}=1+\left((2 k+1)^2+1\right) (z-1)+(2 k+1)^2 \left(2 k^2+2
   k+1\right) (z-1)^2+O\left((z-1)^3\right)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k z^{(2k+1)^2+1}=(z-2) z+\frac{3}{2}\quad \implies \quad f(z)=(z-1) \left(z^2+2 z-2\right)$$ which is negative.

Ckecking the summation

- for $z=\frac{95}{100}$, the numerical value is $0.503482$ while the above approximation gives $\frac{201}{400}=0.502500$
- for $z=\frac{99}{100}$, the numerical value is $0.500105$ while the above approximation gives $\frac{5001}{10000}=0.500100$

I have serious divergence problems when I try to make the expansion to $O\left((z-1)^4\right)$.

If it was
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k z^{(2k+0)^2+1}=\frac{1}{2} z \left(\vartheta _4\left(0,z^4\right)+1\right)$$ the plot of the two $f(z)$ are quite similar. May be, an idea here ?

Comment: The function is quite similar to the theta-function, but not really the theta-function. For your approximation, is there any way to show $f(z) \sim (z-1)(z^2+2z-2)$ as $z\to 1$?

Comment: @KennethNg. I do not understand. This is what I wrote.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Did you plug in the expression $1+((2k+1)^2+1)(z-1) + (2k+1)^2(2k^2+2k+1)(z-1)^2$ into the summation? How do you deal with terms like $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k(2k+1)^2$ then?

Comment: @KennethNg. Just summing the whole expression. This leads to an hypergeometric function which simplifies a lot (as written)

Comment: Hi Claude. Thanks for your comment. Would you mind showing a few steps that will lead to the asymptotic expression? I am not very familiar with these special function. I can continue on it after some hints. Many thanks!

Comment: @KennethNg. It would be too long to type here the  $ \, _5F_4(\cdots)$ function which is the result of the summation over $k$ for the series truncated to $O\left((z-1)^3\right)$. I must confess that I have been more than surprized when I have been able to simplify it so much. Just to give you an idea, the arguments are things like $$\sqrt{\frac{z+1\pm\sqrt{(z-6) z+1}}{8 (1-z)} }$$

Comment: I tried to plug in the expansion into the summation and arrive at $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\{ (8k^4+16k^3)(z-1)^2 + k^2(14(z-1)^2+4(z-1)) + k(6(z-1)^2+4(z-1)) + 2z-1 \}. $$, but I have no idea how to proceed to write it as a hypergeometric function, and simplify it as in your clean polynomial. If typing here is too long, do you mind if I contact you privately to get more idea of how to proceed? Many thanks for your help!